# Heroku bundle fails with Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: bad response backend read error 503

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, bundler

I can't seem to deploy to Heroku. It keeps failing on bundle. I'm able to bundle locally. I'm getting the following error:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: bad response backend read error 503 (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/thor-0.18.1.gem)
An error occurred while installing thor (0.18.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install thor -v '0.18.1'` succeeds before bundling.
!
!     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
!
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

I tried changing the Gemfile source from `"https://rubygems.org"` to `"http://rubygems.org"` without any success. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Are you able to install that version of the gem locally?

Comment: Yes. It installs successfully.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your Gemfile.lock and running bundle?

Comment: Yes. Twice. No change on Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I needed to add the "unf" gem to my Gemfile. After adding that bundle succeeded on Heroku.